# Angular.js and Rails - Directive Rendering TemplateUrl Infinite Loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angularjs-directive, infinite-loop, angular-template

I'm trying to create a custom directive called `message` which renders a html snippet template `message.html`. I am using Angular.js alongside Ruby/ Rails. When I load the page it goes into an infinite loop (might be a recursive directive from what I've read on SO). Any ideas? Much appreciated!!

---

```js
app.directive('message', ['$compile', '$templateCache', function factory($compile) {
  'use strict';
  var messageObject = {
    templateUrl: "<%= asset_path('templates/message.html') %>",
    controller: function(){
      UserService.userHash();
    }
    transclude: true,
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true
  };
  return messageObject;
}]);
```

---

**message.html**

```html
<div ng-transclude>
  MESSAGE WORKS!
</div>
```

---

How I'm using the directive in my `profile.html`

```html
<message></message>
```

This is my Github repo for more information: https://github.com/natbatwat/shori/tree/master/app/assets/javascripts

Comment: I have had a lot of problems with rails includes in angular. I keep all my .html files in ./public in my rails project. So when I want to load a html page with Angular I call this for example: `.when '/',
   templateUrl: 'templates/dashboard/index.html',
   controller: 'DashboardCtrl'`

Comment: Notice that I dont use `<%= %>` tags. But this method required you to keep all html files in public folder!